# Cannot rm broken NTFS link

Tags: symlink, rm, ntfs, hard-link, ntfs-3g

I'm trying to use an old windows NTFS drive as extra storage on a raspberry pi. I tried to delete everything on it, but came across a problem where I can't remove two broken links. I can format the drive entirely, but wanted to know if there's a solution to this before quitting.

I mounted the drive read-write to /media/pi/hdd and ran

```
cd /media/pi/hdd
rm -v -r *
```

Eventually, everything deleted except two files in the following directory: **Program\ Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_17.8830.7600.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe/VFS/**

Listing the contents of that directory:

```
ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Feb 10  2018 ProgramFilesCommonX86 -> unsupported reparse point
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Feb 10  2018 SystemX86 -> unsupported reparse point
```

If I do a 'touch foo', the results change:

```
ls: cannot access 'ProgramFilesCommonX86': Input/output error
ls: cannot access 'SystemX86': Input/output error
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 28 19:59 foo
d????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? ProgramFilesCommonX86
d????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? SystemX86
```

I've tried the following commands but to no avail:

```
rm -rfd *
# rm: cannot remove 'ProgramFilesCommonX86': Directory not empty
# rm: cannot remove 'SystemX86': Directory not empty

unlink ProgramFilesCommonX86
# unlink: cannot unlink 'ProgramFilesCommonX86': Directory not empty
```

Genius idea: Tried to overwrite link to another file but that didn't work either.

```
touch foo
ln -sfn foo ProgramFilesCommonX86
# ln: cannot remove 'ProgramFilesCommonX86': Directory not empty
```

Is this a specific NTFS related issue that can't be fixed because I'm in a Linux environment? Or is there a command or switch that I'm overlooking, or something else entirely?

---

Edit (semi-answer):
I did not find a solution in a Linux environment.

I used the Windows chkdsk command to fix any errors, then I deleted those two files/links/directories manually within Windows after changing the owner to myself.

Although this fixed the issue, the chkdsk command created another file/link under $RECYCLE.BIN that has the same problem. I was unable to remove that file because it didn't show up in the Windows File Explorer and I couldn't figure out how to change the owner through the command line.

Should have formatted it from the start.

Comment: Why not just reformat the drive as ext4?

Comment: I wanted to be able to go back and forth with Windows... I will do that if there isn't a simple solution

Comment: Oh, ok - then reformat the drive as ntfs.

Comment: Ah... that makes a lot of sense, thank you :)